# Write Data to go_maps_ext in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

my problem is the following: 
I have multiple websites in typo3 an want to add the go_maps_ext to all of them. It would be very much work to type the address and coordinates manualy to all of them, so i wrote a extension which gets the data out of an database. My problem now is that I don't know how to pass the values I got to my extension. i need to create a new go_maps_ext-Map and pass the values address, latitude and longitude to it. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

A fast and simple solution woud be to export the table-data from your database and import it to your other databases.

The relevant tables are called:

tx_gomapsext_domain_model_address

tx_gomapsext_domain_model_map

tx_gomapsext_map_address_mm

You can export the data from the tables above via phpmyadmin and then write a simple script (maybe in php) which then imports the data to all your other databases, therefore recreating your go_maps_ext map/address(marker)-object structure in your typo3 Website.

The only thing you maybe need to change from your exported data is the pid(the reference to the page-object which holds the map/address-object). into the desired pid-reference number.

Comment: And where do I find these tables? And how do I pass the data from these tables to about 300 extensions(about 300 websites)?

Comment: Ok. Just found em as php-Files. But how do I pass the values to them?

Comment: You probably missunderstood my answer. I will edit it to be more detailed when i come home (around 2 hours from now). It woud help alot if you coud tell me what database-system(s) you are using on your typo3 websites (mySQL or something else?).

Comment: Yes. Its MySQL via phpMyAdmin